# Short story about scientist who collects dinosaur eggs from the past

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

There is a short story I read in a collection at be beginning of the 90's, I'm trying to find its title and who wrote it.

A scientist team was working on a time travel device. It don't really work until they open a window into the past and retrieve what turn out to be some dinosaur eggs. Unfortunately, they are unable to repeat their success and they lose their funding.

> Meanwhile, the eggs eventually hatch and the poor and starving scientist have no other choice than to eat the dinosaur to survive. The dinosaur meat is so delicious that the Dino-Berger become the must praised food on earth.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That would be '[A Statue for Father](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Statue_for_Father)' by Asimov, usually spotted in '[Buy Jupiter and Other Stories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buy_Jupiter_and_Other_Stories).'

Stealing from the Wikipedia description:

> A theoretical physicist and his son work on the theory of time travel, and experiment with a method of reaching back into time and retrieving objects (as also occurs in "The Ugly Little Boy" and "Button, Button").
>
> More by serendipity than design, they manage to retrieve a nest of dinosaur eggs which in due course hatch. They keep on working but are unable to repeat the experiment. In the meantime, the dinosaurs grow and are kept as pets. But when one of them accidentally gets electrocuted, they can't resist tasting the flesh beneath the scales and find that it tastes delicious.
>
> The two men decide to raise the dinosaurs to be killed for food and open the first of a successful chain of restaurants dedicated to serving "dino-chicken".
>
> The ironic twist of the title is that the physicist is remembered not for his scientific achievements, but for his culinary discovery.